# Selenium: WebDriver blocks when switchs to newly opened window

Tags: selenium

In selenium, `WebDriver.switchTo().window(aWindowHander)` is used to switch defferent windows. But I have an issue in IE9:

When a button is clicked, A new window is opened by javascript, I think.  And `WebDriver.getWindowHandles()` returns two window handlers. That means the new opend window is detected. But `WebDriver.switchTo.window(newOpenedWindow)` is blocked whitout error, blocking for ever. No exception, no error, just block here. It seems the new window always get focus.

I havn't tried other browsers because IE9 is used only for some reason.

Oh, my god! Some one can give me some help?

===updated for code snippet===

```
WebElement input = webDriver.findElement(By.id("inputField"));
input.sendKeys("hello");
/* Make a 'tab' opertation to lose focus. 
 * This will trigger the new window opening.
 * Unfortunately, the web site is not mine. 
 * And only IE support, some detail javascript is not read clearly.
 * I can't be sure that how the new winodw opens. It seems to use
 * 'window.location = newurl' for doing that.
 */
input.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);

//Now the window opened. So here return the handle with size = 2
Set<String> handles = webDriver.getWindowHandles();

for(String handle : handles)
{
    if(!mainWinHander.equals(handle))
    {
        // Here will block for ever. No exception and timeout!
        webDriver.switchTo().window(handle);
    }
}
```

This code works for This post [modal dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936167/how-to-deal-with-modaldialog-using-selenium-webdriver). An example link at http://tinyurl.com/ykt97gx. But doesn't work for my issue. So the main point should be the way of the new window opened. And the page consists of several frames. I tried to build a website to simulate the situation for opening such window, but failed. The real web site need enterpise vpn to visit. So it can't be visited outside.

Comment: Please give a snippet of your code. I have done it in one of my project so i can help you.

Comment: I have updated the question. And please notice the comments in the code.

Comment: Can you show the code where `mainWinHander` is set?

Comment: mainWinHandler is set after driver.getUrl("some_url"), like: webDriver.getUrl("xxx"); mainWinHandler = webDriver.getWindowHandler();

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the cause is that the popup isn't ready. Execute the sentence document.readyState from the console of firebug for instance. If the result isn't "complete" the problem is there.

I have the same problema because the popup remain in state "Loading" and the driver.swhichTo(xxx).window not runs if the state isn't "complete".

Answer (score 0):

That's bang on, this is  using Chrome....Version 70.0.3538.67 (Official Build) (64-bit). I'm trying to build a non-blocking test suite - look like the whole thing locks up while readyState is "loading"

```
document.readyState;
"loading"
dojo.js?xxxxxxxx [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
req.getText @ xxxxxxx
document.readyState;
document.readyState
document.readyState
document.readyState
document.readyState
document.readyState
document.readyState
document.readyState
document.readyState
"loading"
"loading"
"loading"
"loading"
"loading"
"loading"
"loading"
"loading"
"loading"
document.readyState
"loading"
```

....and after an age......

```
document.readyState;
"complete"
```

At which point the getElementById functions etc, start returning.