# Selenium: How to handle a modal dialog that is shown based on number of redirections

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver using C# (Page Factory model).

My application under test gives a feedback dialog after the 3rd redirection on the site, no matter what page user is on.

What would be the best way to handle this feedback dialog? I need to simply close the dialog.

Should I check for this in constructor of each page ?
or 
should I keep a count of redirections using some global variable at test case level and check, in this case how should I keep a track of redirections?

or any other better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a c# selenium coding Tester(i use Java). For Model Dialog we can use this based on this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/MHsIfCaJ7co).

```
private bool IsAlertPresent()
    {
        try
        {
            driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
            return true;
        }
        catch (NoAlertPresentException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private string CloseAlertAndGetItsText() {
        try {
            IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
            string alertText = alert.Text;
            if (acceptNextAlert) {
                alert.Accept();
            } else {
                alert.Dismiss();
            }
            return alertText;
        } finally {
            acceptNextAlert = true;
        }
    }
```

and based on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936167/how-to-deal-with-modaldialog-using-selenium-webdriver). we can also use

WebDriver popup = webDriver.switchTo().window(handle);

```
    popup.close();
```

you can also check this link [Model Dialog](http://selenium-tutorial.blogspot.in/2012/08/webdriver-popup-alert.html)

Comment: Well the problem is, it is a modal dialog, not a JS Alert. :(

Comment: I use a method that waits for the expected alert by wrapping the above IsAlertPresent() in a "For - If" loop, as sometimes there can be a delay in the Alert becoming visible.