# How to handle this popup in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to handle this popup in selenium *webdriver*

Actually it has only div id. no frame, window names. it's just a modal think.

Trying to click the buttons. But, unfortunately can't get focus of this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[9]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/button")).getText();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[9]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/button")).click();
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23Neu.png)

Comment: Please provide html and clarify the problem little bit more. Not information provided to identify the issue

Comment: Try this question about modal dialogs (I think the solution works for IE) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936167/how-to-deal-with-modaldialog-using-selenium-webdriver.