# Unable to find locate frame/Modal Dialog from sitecore and do actions inside

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, modal-dialog, sitecore, sitecore7

Below is the screenshot of the page I'm stuck:

[image]

Below is the screenshot of the HTML:

[image]

HTML

```
<iframe id="scContentIframeId0" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content ui-dialog-normal" src="/sitecore/shell/Applications/Dialogs/External link.aspx?hdl=F66BB6924018478682797A717320B5DB&amp;ro&amp;la=en&amp;sc_content" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; max-height: none; height: 285px;"></iframe>
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-draggable ui-resizable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-describedby="scContentIframeId0" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" style="position: absolute; height: auto; width: 500px; top: 117.5px; left: 308px; display: block; opacity: 1;">
   <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
      <span id="ui-id-1" class="ui-dialog-title">&nbsp;</span>
      <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar-buttonpane" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; right: 0.3em; margin-top: -10px; height: 18px;"><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="close" style="position: relative; float: right; top: auto; right: auto; margin: 0px;"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span><span class="ui-button-text">close</span></button><a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-restore ui-corner-all ui-state-default" href="#" role="button" style="display: none;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-newwin">restore</span></a><a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-collapse ui-corner-all ui-state-default" href="#" role="button" style="display: none;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s">collapse</span></a><a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-maximize ui-corner-all ui-state-default" href="#" role="button"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-extlink">maximize</span></a><a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-minimize ui-corner-all ui-state-default" href="#" role="button" style="display: none;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minus">minimize</span></a></div>
   </div>
   <iframe id="scContentIframeId0" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content ui-dialog-normal" src="/sitecore/shell/Applications/Dialogs/External link.aspx?hdl=F66BB6924018478682797A717320B5DB&amp;ro&amp;la=en&amp;sc_content" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; max-height: none; height: 285px;"></iframe>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
</div>
```

I am trying to find this frame and do actions inside it by locating the elements. But am unable to do so. Tried with Frame id - scContentIframeId0, Xpaths, classnames but no results.

Below is my Selenium c# code

```
IWebElement IFrame = driver.FindElement(By.Id("scContentIframeId0"));
            driver.SwitchTo().Frame(IFrame);
IWebElement LinkDescription = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='Text']"));
            LinkDescription.SendKeys("External Link");
IWebElement URL = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='Url']"));
            URL.SendKeys("www.irctc.co.in");
            IWebElement OKButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='OK']"));

            OKButton.Click();
```

Please help.

Exception Stack Trace Result:

```
Test method ComcastnowTest.Content_Event_RSVP_US688833.EventRSVPlink threw exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"scContentIframeId0"}
  (Session info: chrome=52.0.2743.116)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.23.409699 (49b0fa931cda1caad0ae15b7d1b68004acd05129),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
Result StackTrace:  
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementById(String id)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Id>b__0(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
   at ComcastnowTest.Content_Event_RSVP_US688833.EventRSVPlink()
```

Comment: And which element do you want to locate actually??

Comment: Please see the screenshot from the link provided. you will see a frame in the screenshot and inside I want to do actions with its elements. But the problem, my code doesn't recognise the frame itself and as such am unable to proceed further

Comment: As I'm seeing in provided HTML `iframe` starting then closing no element present inside these `iframes`?? so are you sure desire element is inside an `iframe`?? and which element you want to locate actually?? because in provided HTML there is no element present with id `Text`, `Url` or `Ok`. So could you elaborate more about your question..

Comment: attached HTML screenshot for the elements inside the frame

Comment: Ok I have provided it as an answer, try with it and let me know..

Comment: Are you sure there is only one iframe present or this iframe inside any other iframe, try once to determine how many iframe there as `driver.FindElements(By.TagName("iframe")).Count` and look how many count being returned. also make sure you're trying in defaultContent. If you're already inside any iframe and desire iframe is outside from existing one you need to switch back to default content first then go to this iframe as `driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent()`

Answer (score 1):

If there is any error in your frame code, then the browser will not execute that code and it will not appear in your website. So, you should first confirm that the frame is correct.

You can try this:

```
<div id="anyNameToFind">
  <span>here is the frame in website</span>
  <frame></frame>
</div>
```

However, you should first check weather your  is working.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is timing issue, you should try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until iframe present on the `DOM` then switch to it as :-

```
IWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

//Now wait for iframe to available and then switch 
 wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("scContentIframeId0"));

//Now find desire element inside this iframe 
IWebElement LinkDescription = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("Text")));
LinkDescription.SendKeys("External Link");

//Now after performing all stuff inside iframe switch back to default content 
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but still m getting the error

Comment: Result Message: 
Test method ComcastnowTest.Content_Event_RSVP_US688833.EventRSVPlink threw exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: Timed out after 3 seconds
Result StackTrace: 
at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.ThrowTimeoutException(String exceptionMessage, Exception lastException)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)

Comment: On Second thoughts , I was also thinking whether this could be related to modal box. But, hey any solution which could crack this would be handy!!

Comment: @RuthlessNike Could you tell me in which line this `TimeoutExceptio‌​n` occured?? during frame switching or during finding element by id??

Comment: It happened after frame switching. It is simply not identifying the frame at all.

Comment: @RuthlessNike Sorry I didn't understand, is this switching to frame successfully or throwing exception at that moment??

Comment: Throwing Exception at that moment

Comment: Means frameId `scContentIframeId0` is not unique, I think its dynamically changes, not try to switch with partial match with id as `wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.CssSelector("iframe[id*= 'scContentIframeId']")));` and let me know

Comment: Its giving me exception imed out after 15 seconds ---> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"if‌​rame[id*= 'scContentIframeId']"}
  (Session info: chrome=52.0.2743.116)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.23.409699 (49b0fa931cda1caad0ae15b7d1b68004acd05129),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

Comment: Ah, try once using `TagName` as `wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToI‌​t(By.TagName("if‌​rame")));`

Comment: Same exception as above.

Comment: @RuthlessNike Are you sure, there is `iframe` present when you are going to execute this code??

Comment: Yeah, as I see from the HTML shared . What u think?

Comment: There is also another approach i sought out , it worked but it won't serve the purpose. If we try open it as a web page through the external link mentioned in HTML, then i can locate the elements and do actions. However, once done, my changes won't reflect in the parent window at all.

Comment: @RuthlessNike Could you share URL for this website?? that's why I can suggest you better approach..

Comment: URL : https://admin-dev.comcastnow.com/sitecore/shell/Applications/Dialogs/External link.aspx?hdl=D94110E4A3254C4993A019FF47144220&ro&la=en&sc_content

Comment: @RuthlessNike Not opening in my end, is there some specific configuration to open this website??

Comment: I believe, this is related to Modal dialogue box as i see that once it opens, the parent window behind gets disabled . I think may be the commands in Selenium are not becoming actionable due to this. I believe we need to change the approach towards handling this feature with modal dialogue. May be we can find something out there if we are not getting any solution

Comment: HMM, without seeing live scenario it's hard to say what is the issue in your case, Thanks..:)

Comment: @Sourav - Thanks for the time u gave in cracking this one. Appreciate it. however thinking of other options, here are my queries to u a) can Selenium handle this feature with modal box. If there is how as i am seeing selenium webdriver may not support this feature. If i am wrong ,please correct me.b) If u can share any sample code for it to relate with handling modal dialogues, it could be handy!. Thanks

Comment: I got the below example to handle the Modal Dialog box using selenium with Java. Hope this might help you.        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936167/how-to-deal-with-modaldialog-using-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue and eventually got this working by switching to the `jqueryModalDialogsFrame` first and then `scContentIframeId0` could be found.

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("jqueryModalDialogsFrame");
```

then

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("scContentIframeId0");
```