# How to access Modal Dialog Table window in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I've got a 'window' that appears to pop up on the screen, but I don't believe it's really a pop up window.

Here's what it looks like on-screen:
[image]

Using the browser's `inspect` function on this gives me an `Rel XPath` of:
`//table[@class='DialogFrameContainer']`

When I dug into the CSS sheets of this pop up, it is described in the comments as a `Modal Dialog` using a table.

There are more screenshots of it and the CSS code at the bottom of this question.

I can't figure out exactly what it is (so I could be wrong and it is a pop up window), but I want to click the 'Yes' button on it and can't figure out how.

I have tried to use the following pattern used to handle pop up alerts and it does not work. It prints `no alert` and then the program crashes b/c the `driver` is still stuck on the same window:

```py
        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.alert_is_present(),
                                           'Timed out waiting for PA creation ' +
                                           'confirmation popup to appear.')
            alert = driver.switch_to.alert
            print("alert accepted")
        except:
            print("no alert")
            continue
```

I've also tried this pattern to try to get the `title` of the window, but it only gives me the `title` of the single main page I started on, meaning `selenium` is identifying only one page:

```
    handles = driver.window_handles
    size = len(handles)

    for x in range(size):
      driver.switch_to.window(handles[x])
      print(driver.title)
```

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936167/how-to-deal-with-modaldialog-using-selenium-webdriver) solution, which doesn't work b/c there's only one window.

The pop-up window's `Rel XPath` is:

```
//table[@class='DialogFrameContainer']
```

And the 'Yes' button inside of it changes it's Namespace every session, so I am looking for a solution that clicks on the button that starts with `btnYes_Namespace`.  Here's the text of what the actual button relative XPath was for the session in the screenshots below:

```
//span[@id='btnYes_Namespace_58f12742_b57c_48d7_b0a6_6e3604bc50e1_Label']
```

**Question Updates:**

Per @JeffC's answer I tried the following:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[./span[.='Yes']]").click()
```

Which did not work, and since the button name starts with `btnYes_Namespace` but then contains a string which changes every session I adapted his code and tried the following:

```py
            try:
                found_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'btn')]")
                for button in found_buttons:
                    print(button.text)
            except:
                print('Something went wrong')
```

Which printed out the names of all the buttons on the main page, but not this 'pop up' page and no buttons that contain the text `Yes` in them.

To take it a step further I tried this code:

```py
            try:
                yes_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Yes')]")
                for yes in yes_buttons:
                    print(yes.text)
            except:
                print('Something did not work right.')
```

And nothing printed out.

While working on this I found this CSS code that might be helpful:

```css
/* Modal Dialogs */
/* TODO: delete this declaration when modal dialog frames no longer use tables */
table.DialogFrameContainer, table.DialogContentContainer, .DialogFrameHeader table
{
  width: 100%;

  /* not structurally necessary at all but this helps us separate our inset and outset borders for a certain effect */
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.DialogFrameContainer
{
}
table.DialogFrameContainer
{
  background-color: #eee;
  border: outset 2px #eee;
}
.DialogFrameHeader
{
  cursor: move;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000080;
  color: #fff;
}
.DialogFrameHeader table
{
  border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;
}
.DialogFrameHeader td
{
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: left;
}
td.DialogFrameHeaderTitleCell
{
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.DialogFrameHeaderTitleCell span
{
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.DialogFrameHeaderCloseCell
{
}
.DialogFrameHeaderCloseIcon
{
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent url('Images/window_close_x.gif') no-repeat center;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  float: right;
  border: outset 2px #eee;
}
.DialogContentContainer
{
}
.DialogContent
{
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
table.DialogContentContainer
{
  border: inset 1px #eee;
}
```

Comment: it's got an id so you can use that.  Looks like only one button that contains "btnYes" on that page so an XPATH of "//a[contains(@id, 'btnYes')]" should work.  It sure does look like that's a new window though... what does size return? size = len(handles)

Comment: The screenshots of the UI are nice but please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the HTML as text and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0):

`EC.alert_is_present()` only works with JS alerts. Since you've seen that this "alert" has HTML, that means it's not a JS alert but is instead a popup or window. It looks like you've already investigated the separate window and found that it's not a separate browser window (number of window handles is 1) so that means it's a popup... it's part of the main page's HTML. It also doesn't appear to be in an IFRAME.

This should click the Yes button.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[./span[.='Yes']]").click()
```

You may need to add a wait to ensure that the dialog is fully loaded before attempting the click. With a wait...

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

...

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[./span[.='Yes']]"))).click()
```

Comment: per your comment and answer I've updated my question with new information, i.e. `Modal Dialog` is a `table` on this page, `CSS` in case it's helpful, and reduced the # of screenshots after reading your link.  Thank you for helping me ask better questions and helping with this Q.

Comment: Did you look to see if this popup is in an IFRAME? From looking at your screenshots before it didn't look like it but the more you describe it and all the "Frame" references in the CSS makes me think maybe it is.

Comment: I got the script working by adding this code: `time.sleep(0.25)
            yes_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Yes')]")
            yes_buttons[1].click() ` But it feels hacky, I can't figure out where these Yes buttons are or what window/table/iframe they are hidden in.   Maybe this helps find a real answer?

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't `iframe` , this way can be use:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

s = Service('C:/Users/.../chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

# Open first dialog such as login!
log_in_f = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.H\(40px\).Px\(28px\)')
log_in_f.click()

time.sleep(5)
# open second dialog such as log in by phone 
phone_path='div:nth-child(4) > span > div:nth-child(3) > button'
log_in_s = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, phone_path)
log_in_s.click()

time.sleep(5)
# Open third dialog such as to verify 
close_path=' div > div.Pos\(a\).T\(0\).P\(20px\).P\(12px\)--xs.End\(0\).D\(b\) > button'
log_in_t = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, close_path)
log_in_t.click()
```