# Selenium IDE - find element in new "Window" which is not window

Tags: java, testing, gwt, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I have following problem with Selenium IDE:

I need to click on element which is appearing into new window- it is new input, where i need to type value.

But the problematic is fact, that it is not new window literally, but something like "collections of new elements" which finally looks like window. It's like that, because the application is coding in Java and nextly it is parse to frontend technologies by GWT.

And the question is: how I can find that element on website? When I tryin to find it the regular way- I mean:

```
click | xpath//=...|
```

Selenium IDE couldn't find that element, it is hanging and after a few time it shows error.

I tried to check any element on that "window" by Asserts or by Wait for element visible and wait for texr, but both of this casus gave same result - nothing ;/. It looks like Selenium is not aware that it's actually exists..

Do anyone could help me with that?

Have a great day!

Comment: Never heard about html modals?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply! Truly, I never heard about that. How it could help me with my problem? 

I've checked into web, that problem could be use the GWT for generate teh website which i trying to automate test with Selenium IDE. I have read, that Selenium IDE not cooperate with GWT, I mean, that there could be problems with automate tests...Do modals could help me with that? How to? Please expand this thought.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with ModalDialog using selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936167/how-to-deal-with-modaldialog-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Nope :( The solution which you linked is about the Selenium WebDriver. My  problem refers to Selenium IDE, thats two different things. Anyway, thanks for your help willingness.